# Display real-time data to a web page through Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using  Firebase Realtime Database to store some data and i also have a website that is showing/changing an image src according to a data change.

I have written a javascipt that is changing the html image source whenever a data is triggered from Firebase but i would like that to work at the backend. I want that image to change even if no one visits the site. How can i do that?

Comment: If the database changes, then somewhere there must already be code running that makes that change. That same place can then also make the other change that you're talking about. Alternatively you can run it in Cloud Functions, but that adds a layer of complexity you may not need (or be ready for yet). It'll be easier to give more specific help if you share the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to preserve on a state.

For example, create some database that saved on every user his current "step", and your frontend app will query this database.

Comment: Here is my code [link](https://codeshare.io/ankrMX).

And what if no user is entering the site? I want that to be changed automatically
@Frank van Puffelen